# Multiple calls after AJAX success call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Below, am making an AJAX call. First it has to hit the dofirstthing.do. On success of it, it has to make a call with "param1" as the query parameter.

My question - I need to make another call with "param2" as the query parameter after above call. Not sure how to?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "dofirstthing.do",
    jsonp: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    statusCode: {
        200: function () {
            global.location.search = param1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: _"On success of it, it has to make a call with "param1" as the query parameter"_  Is `"param1"` string ? , Is "make a call" an `$.ajax()` request ?

Comment: you can try with  success:function(data) {
      
    }  in ajax or can you more elaborate your question

Comment: Where is "param2" defined ?

Comment: still not clear , what 's question??

Comment: By modifying the `location`, you're instructing the browser to leave the current page, destroying everything that was in it. The new page (or new instance of the current page) will have to manually determine that `param1` was used and proceed to `param2` instead of repeating `dofirstthing.do`.

Comment: param1 and param2 are 2 strings which are actually the query params to be called in the same sequence. Right now am able to make a call with param1. i need to make a call with param2 after that.

Answer (score 3):

You can chain the ajax calls like this

```
$.ajax({..}).then(function(data1){
    return $.ajax({..});
}).then(function(data2){
    return $.ajax({..});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function on success or fail as this:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery `deferred.then()` , defining an error function

```
var err = function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown)
}

$.ajax({
  url: "dofirstthing.do",
  jsonp: false,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  statusCode: {
    200: function() {
      global.location.search = param1;
      $.get("/url?" + "param1=" + global.location.search)
        .then(function() {
          $.get("/url?" + "param2=" + param2).then(null, err)
        }, err)
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers a `$.get()` function that returns a promise.

You can chain your requests.

see https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a chain of callbacks ---

```
function sendAjax(target,callback)
{
$.ajax({
    url: target,
    jsonp: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    statusCode: {
        200: callback
    }
});
}
```

Now call Your function as -

```
sendAjax("dofirstthing.do",function(data){
       sendAjax("dofirstthing.do?param1="+data,function(data){
           sendAjax("dofirstthing.do?param2="+data,function(data){
              return ;
           });
       });
});
```